# Printing a X using * in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I have to write a python program which allows a user to input an odd integer, n,  greater than or equal to three.  The program outputs an x with n rows and n columns. *My professor said using nested for loops would be ideal for this. The X is printed using *'s *

I have been experimenting over the past couple days and have had little success.
This is my starting code for the program and after that it's just blank, like my mind. If you could provide some explanation as to how the code works that would be amazing.

`num=int(input("Please type in an odd integer."))
 if num%2==0:
    print("Your number is incorrect")`

Comment: Do you have to print out the shape 'X' using asterisks?

Comment: Yes, an example input of 5 would output a X that is 5 columns long and 5 rows wide.

Comment: My suggestion is to draw out an output, using the first 3 inputs (3, 5, 7). Then compare the pattern in each one, and draw conclusions regarding how the number of *'s and spaces change with each increase in input.

Comment: @ViktorTW What is the rule to go from one line to the next?

Comment: @Natecat He didn't specify any rules on anything. He just said we would be using nested for loops.

Comment: @MikiP Thanks for the suggestion! I can definitely see a pattern starting to develop. The number of spaces and *'s are increasing by 1 on each line as the input increases.

Comment: @ViktorTW I was trying to get you to figure it out yourself. Once you have the rule, it should be fairly trivial to implement a loop that uses that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

**Python 2**

```
N = 5

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i == j) or ((N - j -1) == i):
            print '*',
        else:
            print ' ',
    print ''
```

**Python 3**

```
N = 5

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i == j) or ((N - j -1) == i):
            print('*', end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
    print('')
```

(thanks to Blckknght for Python 3 knowledge)

You're looping through all the rows in the outer loop, then all the columns or cells in the inner. The if clause checks whether you're on a diagonal. The comma after the print statement ensures you don't get a new line every print. The 3rd print gives you a new line once you're finished with that row.

If this is helpful / works for you; try making a Y using the same approach and post your code in the comments below. That way you could develop your understanding a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This isn't really working for me sadly :/

Comment: This uses Python 2-style `print` statements. The equivalent in Python 3 syntax would be `print('*', end='')`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using python 3 and was so confused with that. I will try and make the Y and let you know how it works out!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint :

```
n = int(input("Please type in an odd integer."))
for i in range(n):
    print('x', end='')
print()
```

This prints a x, n times on the same line and then go back to next line.

I'll let you figure out how you print this same line n times.

Comment: It's not printing a x like that, I have to print a X using *'s and spaces. I tried to clear that up in the original post up top.

Answer (score 0):

Using single for loop:

```
for i in range(num):
    a = [' '] * num
    a[i] = '*'
    a[num-i-1] = '*'
    print(''.join(a))
```

Using nested for loops:

```
for i in range(num):
    s = ''
    for j in range(num):
        if j in [i, num-i-1]:
            s += '*'
        else:
            s += ' '
    print(s)
```